# EasyMock and Spring RetryTemplate

Tags: spring, junit, easymock

I have class that uses RetryTemplate

```
class UnderTest{
    private RetryTemplate retry;

    public List<String> something(String param){
        retry.execute(new RetryCallback<List<String>>(){

            @Override
            public List<String> doWithRetry(RetryContext context) throws Exception {
                return doSomething(param);
            }

        });
    }
}
```

And now I want mock RetryTemplate using EasyMock that in effect flow will look like (I don't want to test RetryTemplate obviously):

```
class UnderTest{
    private RetryTemplate retry;

    public List<String> something(String param){
        return doSomething(param);
    }
}
```

How to do this with EasyMock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think in case of "transparent" `RetryTemplate` it is just enough to inject to your class something like this:

```
RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(new NeverRetryPolicy());
underTest.setRetryTemplate(retryTemplate); 

underTest.something("foo");
```

Without any mocking.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah that is good, but sometimes solution is not that simple and you want to mock more than that.

You probably mean:

`retry.setRetryPolicy(new SimpleRetryPolicy(1, Collections.<Class<? extends Throwable>, Boolean>emptyMap()));`

Comment: `NeverRetryPolicy` is better. I fixed my answer. And I've just tried to fix your concrete question. Of course, in most cases we should mock a lot, but your use-case won't get deal with that mocks. Of course you can stub `RetryTemplate.execute` and just invoke from there the `RetryCallback` with mock `RetryContext`